# Screen Coordinate to world Transformation using Viewing pipeline ,without shader how do i fix the rotation angle& rotation axis c# opentk

Tags: opengl, opentk

xcc xxx ad dfbqwf qqfef qsqccxw

Comment: could you make a summary on the title? will be easier to index & find for users that might have the answer

Comment: Rotation of cube..how to get it? Using modelview matrix in opentk , opengl c#